# MySQL not saving to separate data directories

Tags: mysql, database, replication, mariadb, database-replication

Lately I've been struggling with MySQL and it's data directory a lot.
At first, I've tried docker for multiple instances but our company doesn't prefer docker no one knows why.

So I come up with a solution.

Some information;

- Multiple servers (6) will send data (like multi-source replication) and one slave
- According to our manager, six is too much dangerous to create a multi-source one slave replica set
- I've ordered additional IP's and configured them.
- Right now, the slave server has 3 IP's from dedicated server provider.
- I can ping those IP's, I can connect to phpmyadmin with new IP's
- The only thing is not working is where MySQL puts the data
- I edited config files and changed all other IP's data directories and ports
- Config files I've edited are in > /etc/mysql/maridadb.conf.d/50-server(n).cnf
- But anytime I create some database in one other IP assigned MySQL, other MySQL IP's can also see and perform actions on it.

***Below you can see the image for maria config's for different instances.***

This part confuses me, since I separated them with different IP's and data directories, how they can still see others. Anytime I create a database in MySQL, it puts to `/var/lib/mysql`.

How can I manage one server, multiple IP's-Ports and multiple MySQL databases without each other seeing/accessing them?

[maria server config settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0aAN.png)

Comment: You say that you're "struggling with the Data Directory" and that what's "not working" is where MySQL/MariaDB puts its data.  The rest of your posting is about something completely different, as far as I can tell. 
Forget this overly-complex, Heath Robinson attempt - what problem are you actually trying to solve?  What's "not working"?

Comment: MySQL always puts the data to /var/lib/mysql even though I configure the data-dir as other location.

Comment: Post the configuration file in which you made this change.

Comment: Is the server "in house" or is it provided by a Cloud company?

Comment: How are you telling it to look in `[mysql1]` and not in `[mysql]` ?

Comment: I am adding configurations to, `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf/50-server(n).cnf`
And activating all the mysql instances with `mysqld_multi start`
In the original question, I've added the screenshot for 50-server1.cnf and 50-server2.cnf
In those config files, I use `datadir` to define the data path that I want mysql to use.
This server is bare-metal provided by hetzner.